# Gauge Fixing in Derivation of Lorentzian OPE Inversion Formula in 2D CFT

Tags: coordinate-systems, field-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions, gauge

I have been looking through the following article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.03816 and wish to understand the derivation from scratch. The definition of conformal partial waves and the object of interest $I_{h,\bar{h}}$ are outlined from Equation 2.1 onwards. The expression in Equation 2.6 is the integral I am puzzled by. The author says that the gauge fixing mentioned leads to Equation 2.7, but I do not understand how fixing $z_5$ at infinity helps us remove the terms in the denominator.

If one goes by the general Faddeev-Popov gauge fixing procedure, we introduce delta functions and the volume of the gauge group vanishes after the integration is done over $z_1, \; z_2 \; \text{and} \; z_5$, but why do the $z_{i5}$ and $\bar{z}_{i5}$ terms go away? Please tell me if I am thinking about the calculation in a wrong manner.

[image]

Comment: Implement $z_5 \to \infty$ by setting $z_5 = 1/x$ and taking $x \to 0$ paying attention to $d^2 z_5$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, just one question - when I take the delta function and the Fadeev Popov determinant, there will be a term which is derivative of (1/x) right? @ConnorBehan

Comment: Yes. This should be cancelled by the fact that other terms have $1-h$ and $1-\bar{h}$ instead of just $-h$ and $-\bar{h}$.