# Faddeev-Popov Method for Gauge Fixing in CFT (Light-ray Operators)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, gauge-theory, conformal-field-theory, gauge

I was attempting to go through the paper by Petr Kravchuk and David Simmons-Duffin: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00098  where I encountered the following

[image]

[image]

Just below E.4, it is mentioned that for the specified gauge : $x_1 = 0$ and $x_2 = \infty$ the FP determinant is $2^d$. Since I am new to CFT calculations, I would like to know how exactly this is done.

I also have a related question: [Gauge Fixing in Derivation of Lorentzian OPE Inversion Formula in 2D CFT](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/780110/)

An explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: This depends on the normalization of the Haar measures on $\mathrm{SO}(2,d)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(1,1)$. Basically, $2^d$ can be viewed as a convention here. However, I think it also does match some natural normalization of the Haar measures. Unfortunately, it seems that we omitted writing it down, and I don't remember the exact definition we used.

Comment: If I had to guess, it is the same as our convention for $\mathrm{SO}(d+2)$ but formally "Wick-rotated". And for $\mathrm{SO}(d+2)$, the convention is that $\mathrm{SO}(n+1)\approx S^n \times \mathrm{SO}(n)$, with standard measure on $S^n$, recursively applied.

Comment: So, I am assuming that it has more to do with the normalisation of the measure itself rather than the FP determinant, which, going by the usual procedure should just be 1?

Comment: I don't really understand your comment. You cannot compute FP determinant without knowing the measures. Knowing the measures gives you an FP determinant. That determinant is not necessarily 1, it will depend on the choice of measure.

Comment: My apologies, I understand what you mean now. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: For example, the paper in your other answer basically uses a convention where a related FP determinant is 1, without specifying the details of the Haar measures. Here the convention is different because it makes the formulas a bit nicer, and I think it is related to a natural normalization of the Haar measure. However, you could just treat this $2^d$ as the definition of the measure, as they do in that other paper.